# How can I find which images are used in my html file from images folder?

Tags: html, image, find

I'm Making a multipage HTML Template. so in my `assets` folder, I have created a folder name `images` which contains all of the images. In my `images` folder, there are some subfolders like `home-1`, `home-2`, `home-3`, `home-4` just like this. Into these folders, there are many unused images which aren't used in HTML file.

Now how can I find all of these unused images?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many images you are using.
But in some IDE's (editors) it is possible to globally search the project folder.
In here you can search for the image name, And if it does not appear in the code, the image does not get used. It will be a pain to search for all of them if you have a lot though.

So let me ask the question. How many images are you talking about?
There is a huge difference between finding 10 images, or 500.

Comment: There are so many images, I guess about 200+. That's why it's giving me the pain to search individually.

Comment: By Googling a bit I have found two different possible methods of finding unused files.
http://www.sobolsoft.com/findunused/ and https://www.inspyder.com/products/OrFind

I think the inspyder Orphan Anaylsis. (the second one) is the most promising. You could try it. Although I do not know the program so I suggest scanning it with a virus scanning and to create a back-up of your folder before accidently deleting a bunch of in-use images.

I hope this works.